# Get all users associated with a custom post type in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a custom post type `institutions` that are associate users.

Whenever I add a new user, I can select which institution he/she is associated with via `Advanced Custom Fields` plugin.

Now that the set up is done, I am trying to display a list of all users associated with the institution I am currently viewing (`single-institutions.php`)

I cannot use `WP_Query()` because it won't allow me to get the users and I can't use `wp_list_authors()` because it won't allow the `meta_query`.

So I am left with using the old fashioned mysql query.

But I'm not sure how to proceed because I need to query multiple tables in order to get the proper result.

```
wp_users: ID
wp_usermeta
    user_id
    meta_key: institution
    meta_value: a:1:{i:0;s:4:"2875";} // "2875" is the ID of the institution the user is associated with
```

How can I achieve this with a direct mysql query?

EDIT: I've switched to `WP_User_Query()` instead, I had no idea it existed. However, I am unsure what to put in `meta_value`

```
$args = array(
  'role'           => 'Author',
  'order'          => 'ASC',
  'orderby'        => 'display_name',
  'who'            => 'authors',
  'exclude'        => [1, 7],
  'count_total'    => true,
  'meta_key'       => 'institution',
  'meta_value'     => $post->ID
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// The User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
  foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
    echo $user->display_name . '<br>';
  }
} else {
  // no users found
}
```

Right now, nothing gets displayed. If I remove "meta_value" from the query, all users associated with any institution appear on all pages.

How do I narrow it down to match the institution ID (`$post->ID`) I am currently viewing?

This is the value of `meta_value` column in `wp_usermeta` table. It's serialized. Do I need to do anything special to retrieve the ID at the end?

```
a:1:{i:0;s:4:"2875";}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) which is similar to `WP_Query`. More specifically, in your case, look at the [Custom Field Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) and send it the `ID` of the institution.

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. Had no idea `WP_User_Query()` exists. However, I am unsure what to use for `meta_value` - I've updated my post if you have a look please.

Comment: It worked. I had to use `LIKE` instead of `=` for `meta_compare`. Thank you.

Comment: @Halnex Ah, correct, I missed the fact that this was a serialized array. Be aware of a couple of caveats here:

1) Doing a meta query with a `LIKE` operator can be expensive if you have a lot of data and may impact site performance. It's usually fine, but if you experience problems, this may be something to look at.

2) You should include double quotes in your `meta_value`, for example `'meta_value' => '"' . $post->ID . '"'`. This way you'll avoid selecting values like `"19"` when you meant to select `"9"`, etc.